# Why does this implementation not allow an @body convertor to be created?

Tags: java, kotlin, openai-api

I have the following code as my OpenAIapi in Kotlin, Android studio:

```
package com.example.pantrypal.apis

import com.example.pantrypal.models.ChatRequest
import com.example.pantrypal.models.ChatResponse
import com.example.pantrypal.models.Message
import com.jakewharton.retrofit2.converter.kotlinx.serialization.asConverterFactory
import kotlinx.serialization.json.Json
import okhttp3.MediaType.Companion.toMediaType
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient
import retrofit2.Retrofit
import retrofit2.http.Body
import retrofit2.http.Headers
import retrofit2.http.POST
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit

interface OpenAIApiService {

    @Headers(
        "Content-Type: application/json",
        "Authorization: Bearer MY-API-KEY"
    )
    @POST("v1/chat/completions")
    suspend fun getChatCompletions(@Body request: ChatRequest) : ChatResponse

}

object OpenAIApi{

    private val httpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .callTimeout(50, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .readTimeout(50, TimeUnit.SECONDS).build()

    private val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
        .addConverterFactory(Json{ ignoreUnknownKeys = true}.asConverterFactory("application/json".toMediaType()))
        //.addConverterFactory(Json.asConverterFactory("application/json".toMediaType()))
        .baseUrl("https://api.openai.com/")
        .client(httpClient)
        .build()

    val retrofitService : OpenAIApiService by lazy{
        retrofit.create(OpenAIApiService::class.java)
    }

    suspend fun getResponse(prompt: String) : String {
        try{
            val chatRequest = ChatRequest(
                model = "gpt-3.5-turbo",
                messages = listOf(
                    Message(
                        role = "user",
                        content = "Hello, how are you?"
                    )//prompt)
                )
            )
            println("before ")
            println("Request Body: $chatRequest")
            val chatResponse = retrofitService.getChatCompletions(chatRequest)
            println("after")
            return chatResponse.choices[0].message.content
        } catch (e: Exception){
            e.printStackTrace()
            return ("Error: " + e.message)
        }
    }

}
```

and the following cod as my API objects:

```
@Serializable
data class ChatRequest(val model: String, val messages: List<Message>, val temperature: Double = 0.8)

@Serializable
data class Message(val role: String, val content: String)

@Serializable
data class ChatResponse(val id: String,
                        @SerialName(value = "object")
                        val object_: String,
                        val created: Long, val model: String, val usage: Usage, val choices: List<Choice>)

@Serializable
data class Usage(val prompt_tokens: Int, val completion_tokens: Int, val total_tokens: Int)

@Serializable
data class Choice(val message: Message, val finish_reason: String, val index: Int)
```

when I try to make a request I get the error:
Unable to create @Body converter for class com.example.pantrypal.models.ChatRequest (paramapter #1) for method OpenAIApiService.getChatCompletions

I have already verified that my emulator has internet connection, that my api-key works and that I have a payment method with OpenAI. I've also made sure all my dependancies are up to date